# How to detect headset sound output and mic input for ALC1220 (asus x570-i motherboard) for Sennheiser HD 450BT headphones?

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-jack

I just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new desktop and making the jack connection (with or without [using a splitter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Headphone-Microphone-Headphones-connector/dp/B073ZDDTH2/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=jack+splitter&qid=1594145174&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExVFdJVlFXNlczQjlXJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjY0OTc0MlEwWE1PUUpKMzY1JmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA2NTQ1OTIzMkc4N0YzTzVOOEdIJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==)) work for sound with mic seems impossible.

I want to use my headphones to hear audio and also communicate using the headphone's mic, but it is not working so far.

#### I have tried everything:

- Upgraded kernel to `5.7.1`
- Clearing pulse config; `rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/`.
- Killing pulseaudio reloading ALSA; `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`
- Finding my Audio Codec (ALC1220->dual-codecs for gaming mobos) and adding the following mapping: `options snd-hda-intel model=dual-codecs` to: `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.
- Installing and using `pavucontrol`.
- `alsactl restore`.
- `apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade`
- shutdown/rebooting several times.

#### The Mic is detected now but not the headset:

[image]

#### Hardware:

Motherboard: ROG Strix X570-I ([specifications](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/ROG-Strix-X570-I-Gaming/specifications/))

- SupremeFX 8-Channel HD Audio **CODEC S1220A** (Supports: Jack-detection, Front Panel Jack-retasking)

Headphones: Sennheiser HD 450BT Headphones ([specifications](https://en-uk.sennheiser.com/wireless-headphones-bluetooth-noise-cancelling-hd-4-50-btnc))

- connectivity: Bluetooth v4.0/NFC pairing

#### `lspci | grep Audio`:

```
0b:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 HDMI Audio
0d:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
```

#### `cat /proc/asound/cards`

```
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfcda0000 irq 138
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfcc00000 irq 140
```

#### `dmesg | grep codec`

```
[    3.102699] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC1220: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    3.102701] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.102702] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.102703] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.102703] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    3.102705] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    3.102706] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    3.102707] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Line=0x1a
```

#### `cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```sh
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
# Add audio for ALC1220 (gaming mobos)
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel model=dual-codecs
```

Comment: I have a few questions:
1) Why do you mention trying with another bluetooth headset, if you are trying to have the audio jack working?
2) Does the Line out connector work fine, and it is only the Mic in that doesn't work? I checked https://files.bbystatic.com/dD7nQUnNSvwe6omQPEIx7w%3D%3D/EC2D725C-CF68-4A05-834E-05B070F05C7F.pdf, Sec. 2.3.2 for the layout.
3) Why not using kernel 5.8.0? (even if that is possibly not the issue)

Comment: Because I had interest to use a Bluetooth headphones. I am using a different headphones now (sony wh-1000xm4) and using kernel 5.11.0-16. Cannot use my headphones for both mic and sound output so I use my webcam for mic support and my new headphones for audio output.

Comment: This question is left here for other people with the same issue. Hopefully, it will give them a small head start.

Comment: So you are not interested anymore in an answer to the question?
If you still are, what is the exact question?

Comment: I would be interested to know the answer, but it is not of urgency for me. I have updated the question to be as specific as possible.

Comment: [`pacmd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/CLI/) is your friend. Your mic (input, source) should be automatically listed: [`pacmd list-sources | grep -e 'index:' -e device.string -e 'name:'`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples#Set_default_input_source), and also your [sinks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/About/) (output; speakers, headphones; `list-sinks`)

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with a similar mobo (MSI MPG X670E), maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1494365/1162719) post will help you somehow. I am also using a splitter.